# Change google-map center using Polymer

Tags: polymer

I'm working on a custom element using  Polymer. I want to change its center after it was rendered. I can't found it on Polymer docs. Anyone could help me?

```
<dom-module id="my-map">
<template>
    <google-map latitude="{{latitude}}" longitude="{{longitude}}" zoom="15">
    </google-map>
</template>
```

```
<script>
Polymer({
    is: "my-map"

    // I want to change map center here
});

    // or here.. I don't know
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `<script>` tag you can create a ready call back function. See [lifecycle callbacks](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements.html#lifecycle-callbacks)

> Polymer adds an extra callback, ready, which is invoked when Polymer has finished creating and initializing the element’s local DOM.

In here you can change the `longitude` and `latitude`  properties of your `my-map` element which you are passing into the `google-map` element:

```
<dom-module id="my-map">
    <style>
        google-map {
            height: 600px;
            width: 600px;
        }
    </style>
    <template>
        <google-map latitude="{{latitude}}" longitude="{{longitude}}" zoom="15"></google-map>
    </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
    Polymer({
        is: "my-map",
        ready: function () {
            this.latitude = 37.77493;
            this.longitude = -122.41942;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Alternatively, if you can give the `longitude` and `lattitude` properties default values ([see here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html)):

```
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: "my-map",
        properties: {
            longitude: {
                type: Number,
                value: -122.41942
            },
            latitude: {
                type: Number,
                value: 37.77493
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I did that, works.. but if I define an event "setLatLng" instead of "ready" and call it from a button tap (allways inside Polymer) the map don't update its center. Ideas?

Comment: I've set up a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8euBzRIsomIqfJfzhngn) here for you. **Please note**, I can't get this to work for on the plunker but if you copy the code it will work locally. If you have removed the `ready` function, you will need to use my second solution where you declare the `longitude` and `latitude` properties.

Comment: I updated the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BRdimDSSMZ9HfC03NUH7?p=preview) adding two lines `var newCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(this.latitude, this.longitude); this.$.map.map.setCenter(newCenter);` and now its working fine. Thank you!